# Continuity in mean of a stochastic process

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

If $X$ is a stochastic process, a.s. continuos and such that $\forall t \geq 0, X_t \in L^1_\omega$, is its mean function $t \rightarrow E[X_t]$ continuos?

I can show it if $X \in L^1_\omega L^{\infty}_t$ which means that $E[\sup_{t \geq0} |X_u|] < \infty$ by the dominated convergence theorem.

Is it true in general?

Comment: Have a look at the counterexample presented [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1583025/36150); the process has continuous sample paths but $t \mapsto E(X_t)$ fails to be continuous (.... which follows from a computation which is very similiar to the one which you find in the linked question).